# Grails can't reference a domain class called Config in plugin

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I created a Grails plugin and created a domain class in it called `Config`:

```
package com.company.common

class Config {

    String defaultTimeZone
    String defaultLanguage
}
```

In another Grails project, I'm including the plugin and I have this line in `Bootstrap.groovy:`

```
import com.company.common.Config
```

Every time I try to run the project though, I get this error:

> C:\Code\grails-app\conf\BootStrap.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.company.common.Config

It works if I have the `Config` domain class in the same Grails project. It also seems to work if I rename it to something like `ProjectConfig` in the plugin project.

Does anyone know why I can't reference a domain class called `Config` in another project?

P.S. All the other domain classes in the plugin project can be accessed from the main Grails project, only the `Config` class gives me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails plugins have specific files that are removed when packaging the plugin (so you can use them for testing). You can find the list here [Grails Plugins #Creating and Installing Plugins](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins). For convenience, here is the list:

```
grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy
grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy (although it is used to generate dependencies.groovy)
grails-app/conf/Config.groovy
grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy (and any other *DataSource.groovy)
grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy
grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
Everything within /web-app/WEB-INF
Everything within /web-app/plugins/**
Everything within /test/**
SCM management files within **/.svn/** and **/CVS/**
```

While this list does not include Config.groovy files in domain class folders, it might be caught by this. Would be worth checking if the Config.groovy file gets carried over to the packaged plugin, or if you can live with renaming the file, that would work as well.